# What does this error mean: "maverick is not supported."

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install AppScale on a cluster, and I'm running this command:

```
debian/appscale_build.sh
```

when I get this error:

```
 maverick is not supported
```

what does this mean? I am unable to understand it.

This is my ubuntu details:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.10  
Release:    10.10
Codename:   maverick
```

Comment: Try to ask at askubuntu.com or superuser.com...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means this AppScale version doesn't support your version of Ubuntu, which is Maverick.

Comment: oh, then what should I do, should I try a different version of AppScale?

Comment: Possibly. I don't know anything about AppScale, so it's hard to say. Maverick is pretty old at this point. Can you upgrade your Ubuntu version? (Is Maverick an LTS?)

Comment: No, I can't I'm using the University's server, so I can't do anything about the OS and stuff

Comment: In that case, I would look at different versions of AppScale to see if anything supports 10.10 then.